# How do I re-enable Kerberos authentication after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: mac-osx, kerberos, osx-yosemite

In previous versions of Mac OS X, one could enable Kerberos authentication when a user logs in by following a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5385).

Specifically, this document explains that the file `/etc/pam.d/authorization` needs to be edited to enable this. After upgrading to Mac OS X10.10, this file no longer exists, and there is no update to the KB article.

Is there a new (and better?) way to enable this feature?

Comment: Is this on a Mac OS X server? Meaning basically a Mac OS X machine that runs the server application?

Comment: No, this is a client. The server is running the Heimdal implementation on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/ITS/Kerberos+on+Mac+OS+X+10.7+and+later

I used this howto sited above and others like it on my yosemite workstation.  I have a centos7 server with IPA on virtual box and kinit and klist work.  I ssh'd afterwards and wasn't automatically ssh'd into the centos/ipa server on the virtual box guest verifying sso.  This was my first setup and I didn't do the ipa install with bind.

This was all done from my mbp.  I also have yosemite server installed, so I don't know if that is why I have the files or not.  I made backups of the originals and edited accordingly to the link above.  Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me on 10.10.0, and those directories exist for me.

I'm also using the Heimdal implementation but on OpenBSD.

[Example Ticket on 10.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5UJG.png)

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/pam.d/authorization`? Did you do an upgrade or a new install?

Comment: @Elias I've got the file /etc/pam.d/authorization on my MBP that I've upgraded to Yosemite. The file is also present on my desktop at work which is a fresh install of Yosemite.

Try look in `/private/etc/` as `/etc/` is a symlink to `/private/etc/`